# ElasticSearch assign own IDs while indexing with LogStash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am indexing a large corpora of information and I have a string-key that I know is unique. I would like to avoid using the search and rather access documents by this artificial identifier.

Since the Path directive is discontinued in ES 1.5, anyone know a workaround to this problem!?

My data look like:

```
{unique-string},val1, val2, val3...
{unique-string2},val4, val5, val6...
```

I am using logstash to index the files and would prefer to fetch the documents through a [direct get](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-get.html), rather than through an exact-match.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Can you share the logstash config you have now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `elasticsearch` output plugin, just specify the `document_id` setting with a reference to the field you want to use as id, i.e. the one named `1` in your `csv` filter.

```
input {
    file {...}
}
filter {
    csv{
        columns=>["1","2","3"]
        separator => ","
    }
}
output {
 elasticsearch {
     action => "index"
     host => "localhost"
     port => "9200"
     index => "index-name" 
     document_id => "%{1}"              <--- add this line
     workers => 2
     cluster => "elasticsearch-cluster"
     protocol => "http"
 }
}
```

Comment: nope. I have only one element added to the index, this is the last element with id: "_id": "%{1}". So the variable is not parsed.

Comment: Can you name the CSV fields with valid field names? i.e. not 1,2,3 but e.g. `col1`, `col2`, etc

Comment: embarrasing :) Thank you :)